# Making a 3D map by interpolation by stacking data for different depths

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, interpolation, qgis2threejs

So, I have the data of shipping Noise levels at various coordinates (300x300 km grid, with 900 coordinates). I have the Noise levels for 5 depths (10m, 30m, 50m, 70m, 90m) and I while I am able to create separate 2D maps for each of the depth, I need to visualize the sound behavior underwater.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: You may try GRASS GIS 3D raster: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/raster3dintro.html